# Trying to use inheritance in kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to create a simple programe that animates my label widget to desired position upon clicking on the kivy window. Just trying to experiment with inheritance to access all the elements in the parent element.
`ani` is the parent class and `transit` is the child class. I am trying to access the `label` attribute in `transit` via inheritance. But this throws error.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class transit(ani,Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        ani.__init__(self,**kwargs)
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        val = 5
        print(touch.x,touch.y)
        self.val +=10
        animation = Animation(x = touch.x,y =touch.y,font_size=self.val,d=2,t='in_out_quad')
        animation.start(self.parent.label)

class ani(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.label = Label(text='increase')

    def build(self):
        return transit()



root = ani()
root.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to use inheritance with the wrong class. If you want to move a `Label`, you need to put the `Label` in a container and make sure the size of the `Label` does not fill the container. Since the position of the `Label` is controlled by its container, you need to use inheritance with the container. Here is a simple code, similar to yours, that uses a `FloatLayout` as the container:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation


class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            val = 5
            label = App.get_running_app().label
            animation = Animation(x = touch.x,y =touch.y,font_size=val,d=2,t='in_out_quad')
            animation.start(label)
        return super(MyFloatLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class ani(App):
    def build(self):
        root = MyFloatLayout()
        self.label = Label(text='increase', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100,40))
        root.add_widget(self.label)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ani().run()
```

This code uses inheritance to define a new `MyFloatLayout` class that adds a new `on_touch_down()` method that does the animation. Note that the new `on_touch_down()` also calls `super(MyFloatLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)`. Unless there is a specific reason for not doing that, you normally want to call the `super` method in an inherited method.